Gmail API in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC
I am working on sending email using Google cloud gmail API with my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application project.
I followed the OAuth 2.0 setup process in the Google Cloud Console and configured my client_id, client_secret, and other required values correctly in my application configuration.

However, when I attempt to authenticate, I'm encountering the following error:

Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

In my code, I added the credentials.json file in the wwwroot folder:
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "my id",
        "project_id": "ums-email-service",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "my sercret",
        "redirect_uris": [ "http://localhost:7268" ]
    }
}

And this is the Google service:
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using MimeKit;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class GmailServiceHelper
{
    private static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };
    private static string ApplicationName = "UMS Email Service";

    public static GmailService GetGmailService()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        string credentialsPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "gmailCreds", "credentials.json");

        using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialsPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = "token.json";

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        if (credential == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Authorization failed. Please check your credentials.");
        }

        return new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
    }

    public static async Task SendEmailAsync(string to, string subject, string bodyText)
    {
        var gmailService = GetGmailService();

        var msg = new MimeMessage();
        msg.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("UMS Email Service", "example@gmail.com")); 
        msg.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", to));
        msg.Subject = subject;

        msg.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = bodyText
        };

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await msg.WriteToAsync(memoryStream);
            var rawMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())
                               .Replace('+', '-')
                               .Replace('/', '_')
                               .Replace("=", "");

            var email = new Message
            {
                Raw = rawMessage
            };

            await gmailService.Users.Messages.Send(email, "me").ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
}


When the debugger reaches this point
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

a new tab is opened and I got

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

I did some Google search and followed the docs and some recommendations, but nothing works

http is not the same as https

no this was a typo mistake by me, its not the problem, I also cleared the cache in my browser, sti having this error

You can try adding under the authorization redirect uri like : http://port/authorize

u mean no need to localhost or loopback address?

Your OAuth credentials include a redirect_uris (missing a path) that appear to not be implemented by your app. Google's auth service expects to callback to your app to exchange tokens, is failing and reporting the error. If you're using an installed app, there's one path, for ASP.NET you should use the Web Applications path
